# Problem with str_if_eq

Tags: expl3, latex3

This must be a really dumb question, but what am i doing wrong here? As far as I can see, the strings are equal, so the test should be successful, instead i get not successful.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_new:N \g_test_str

\NewDocumentCommand{\Test}{m}
 {
  \str_set:Nn \g_test_str { #1 }
  
  \noindent
  Input is #1 \newline
  String is \g_test_str \newline
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { \g_test_str }{test}{test successful}{test not successful}
 }
 
 \ExplSyntaxOff

 \begin{document}
 
 \Test{test}
 
 \end{document}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the `V` variant to receive the contents of a **v**ariable:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_new:N \l_test_str

\NewDocumentCommand {\Test} {m} {
  \str_set:Nn \l_test_str {#1}
  \noindent
  Input~ is~ #1 \newline
  String~ is~ \l_test_str \newline
  \str_if_eq:VnTF \l_test_str {test} {test~ successful} {test~ not~ successful}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
 
\Test{test}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise the unexpanded strings “`\l_test_str`” and “`test`” are compared which are *not* equal.

I also renamed your variable as it is a local one here and not a global one.

Comment: Thank you very much.